# Can I 'un-bridge' a Twilio call in active state and then reconnect my 2 legs in the same call later?

Tags: twilio

As an APP, I want to connect 2 users on a call, 'park' users to an IVR mid-call (active), play prompts and collect DTMF on both sides ("press 1 to continue, 2 to end the call") and reconnect on the SAME call if both selected "1". Thank you.

Comment: You can connect the 2 together by dropping them into the same named conference room.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at conferencing but my calls to the users will be outbound from my APP. Conferences seem to be for inbound calls only. Giving it a second look, see if I can dial users into the conf - should be possible, I guess. Wonder if my APP would have to be the 3rd participant on the call, if so, this would drive my price up by 33% on a peer-to-peer call.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue. You have your app make outbound call, users answer (runs some twiml with a gather command) on your processing request if they pushed 1, then send Dial for Conference command with the same name. I do it all the time on outbound calls. If you have twilio make the outbound to 2 users you are paying for 2 legs already. This won't increase costs by adding another leg, because it doesn't add one.

Answer (score 0):

From Matt's comments above:

1. App makes [outbound call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls)
2. Users answer and respond to [`<Gather>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather)
3. Connect both users to same [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference)

---

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>Room 1234</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```